# Zf2 extending the class giving the error class not found

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2

I am trying to create the library inside the vendor folder in ZF2. Here is the structure:

```
/Vendor
     /Mylib
          /Mylib.php
          /MylibStore.php
          /MylibError.php
          ....
```

I have declared the same lib in **`Applicaiotion/Module.php`**:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                 'Mylib' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/Mylib',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Now I am calling Mylib class in controller it is working but when I am trying to instantiate other class in controller it is giving the error. Here is snap of code:

Mylib.php

```
namespace Mylib;
abstract class Mylib
{
```

MylibStore.php

```
namespace MylibStore;
use \Mylib\MylibError;
class MylibStore extends MylibError
{
```

MylibError.php

```
namespace MylibError;
class MylibError
{
```

I am getting the following error :

> Fatal error:  Class 'MylibStore\MylibError' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\coxaxle\vendor\Mylib\MylibStore.php on line 5

Please let me know what I am doing wrong? And how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your namespaces. All your files inside `Mylib` directory should have same `namespace`- `Mylib`.
That's why only `Mylib` class works, because it has correct `namespace`.

If you put your classes in separate directories then you have to update namespace about this directory.

**Example:**

```
/Vendor
     /Mylib
          /Service
              /MylibService.php
          /Mylib.php
          ....
```

Class `Mylib` should have namespace `Mylib`
Class `MylibService` should have namespace `Mylib\Service`

Comment: I have one question ... If I will give the same namespace to all files then will it not give any conflict?? like same namespace same as give the error for same class name.

Comment: As long as your class names are different, there will not be any conflict